# how remove the first item on drop down with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, hide

here is my code:

```
<select id="List" name="UserType" onChange ="hide">
       <option value="0" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Tipo de Usuario</option>
       <option value="1" onclick="hide">Administrador</option>
       <option value="2" onclick="hide">Moderador</option>
       <option value="3" onclick="hide">Usuario Comun</option>
</select>
```

when i click some value (not zero) in the the drop down, i need remove the first item from this (Tipo de Usuario).  Some code in javascript able to do that?

Comment: Yes, you can do that with Javascript. What did you try?

Comment: list.children[0].remove(); or list.options[0].remove(); or list.removeChild(list.options[0]);

Comment: Dalorzo i saw these post but dont work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can always use this:

```
<option disabled selected style="display:none">Tipo de usuaro</option>
```

Comment: not all browsers respect hiding options via display.

Answer (score 0):

```
function hide(){
    var list = document.getElementById("List");
    list.removeChild(list.childNodes[1]);
}
```

Comment: childNodes includes whitespace, making it dangerous to rely on...

Comment: This will remove the first item even if the selected item is value zero.

Comment: @Gabriel but according to the given html the first item cannot be selected